# how can I use constructors in place of setter member functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

my program basically depends on setters to initialize the data in my object instances but I want to remove them and have constructors in place of the setters, Is there a way I can do this or can anybody provide me a reference?

**Instantiate object**

```
//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <archer.hpp>
#include <ctime> 
#include <ArmouredArcher.hpp>
#include <RNGI.hpp>

    using namespace std; //Declaring use of namespace std

    void instantiateMuskateer();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //init muskateer object
    instantiateMuskateer();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Instantiation, Activity and destruction**

```
void instantiateMuskateer()
{
    Archer* Muskateer = new Archer();

    Muskateer->setName("Brett"); 

    delete Muskateer;
}
```

**.hpp file**

```
#ifndef _Archer_
#define _Archer_

#include <string>

class Archer
{
public:
    inline Archer() :
        name(""),
        healthpoints(0),
        baseDamage(0),
        range(0)
        { ; } //All Member varials are in a known state

    inline Archer(std::string name, int healthpoints, int baseDamage, int range) :
        name(name),
        healthpoints(healthpoints),
        baseDamage(baseDamage),
        range(range) //All member variables are in a known state
    {
        ;
    }

    inline ~Archer() { ; } // empty destructor

    inline std::string getName() { return name; }
    inline void setName(std::string name) { this->name = name; }

    inline int getHealthPoints() { return healthpoints; }
    inline void setHealthPoints(int healthpoints) { this->healthpoints = healthpoints; }

    inline int getBaseDamage() { return baseDamage; }
    inline void setBaseDamage(int baseDamage) { this->baseDamage = baseDamage; }

    inline int getRange() { return range; }
    inline void setRange(int range) { this->range = range; }

    /*std::string getName(); //getter for name
    void setName(std::string name); //Set the name

    int getHealthPoints();
    void setHealthPoints(int healthpoints);

    int getBaseDamage();
    void setBaseDamage(int baseDamage);

    int getRange();
    void setRange(int range); */
protected:
private:
    // copy constructor
    Archer(const Archer& other) = delete;
    // overload assignment operator
    Archer& operator=(const Archer& other) = delete;

    std::string name;
    int healthpoints;
    int baseDamage;
    int range;
};

#endif
```

Comment: What's actually wrong with that code? Looks fine for me at a first glance.

Comment: You may be looking for a [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code is correct but I want to use appropriate constructors in place of the setters but I have no idea how to :(

Comment: @imbrett You mean how to call the constructor? Just pass all the parameters that were declared in the constructor.

Comment: You shouldn't use `inline` when the function definition is inline anyway, it just clutters the screen.  It's meant to be used when the body is out-of-line but you want it to be treated as if it were inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, it is really simple, you just have to take the parameters you need in your constructor:

```
Archer(std::string n) :
        name(n),
        healthpoints(0),
        baseDamage(0),
        range(0)
        {} //All Member varials are in a known state
```

And then you can simply do that:

```
void instantiateMuskateer()
{
    Archer* Muskateer = new Archer("Brett");

    delete Muskateer;
}
```

A few comments not related, but to improve your code. Writing `inline` is useless when you declare and implement your functions inside your class, the `inline` is implied. Also, if your destructor does nothing, you should not define it or use `= default`, that way you can enable some optimizations from the compiler.

Also, in your previous function i see no need to allocate the object on the heap, it is again a loss of performance and a source of error (such as forgetting to `delete` the object), allocate it on the stack:

```
void instantiateMuskateer()
{
    Archer Muskateer("Brett");
    // do your things
}
```

Or use a `unique_ptr`.